# Reproject an Image from Nad83 to Spherical Mercator on a Server

Tags: php, gis, gdal, map-projections

My goal is to take radar images from the NOAA website and reproject them to spherical mercator. Ultimately the images will be consumed by an Android app.

The reprojection will be done on a server via a chron job. I have played with Gdal and like it. My issue is that I cannot build it on my server. I have shared hosting on Network Solutions. To my knowledge I do not have terminal/command line access. Ideally I would run php-gdal but am open to other solutions. Can anyone point me in the right direction to install php-gdal via ftp on a shared host running unix?

I am open to other solutions to reproject these images however I do not want to install a WMS(even if I could find out how). I have heard of Open Layers and Proj4js but am not sure how a Java Script solution would work in a server environment. I would be open to exploring some PHP image transformation as I may be able to make some sore of distort/warp/plane-cylinder type of effect work with some modification. ImageMajik would possibly work but once again I am not sure how to install that on my shared host. Currently my host provides GD support in their build- but it is not adequate to my knowledge..